# How to understand the ski pants size option 'Tall'?

Tags: clothing, skiing, pants

Some ski pants have the size option 'Tall', for example

S size would have inseam length varieties Short, Regular, Long

but there is also a

S Tall size which also has inseam length Short, Regular, Long

What's confusing to me is that if I find both size charts and compare them, the three inseam lengths are the same. So what does 'Tall' mean? What is the actual difference?

Example:

https://www.rei.com/product/156600/the-north-face-freedom-insulated-snow-pants-mens-tall-sizes

https://www.thenorthface.com/en-us/mens/mens-bottoms/mens-pants-c224219/mens-freedom-insulated-pants-pNF0A5ABU

Note the S Tall and S sizes both have the same inseam lengths.

Comment: Regardless of the actual inseam measurement, the overall cut of a Tall or Long vs Regular will be different, leading to a different overall fit.

Comment: maybe just try then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing the inseams as the same.

From the North Face link:

```
Inseams for Short(29.5 in), Medium (31.5 in), and Long (33 in) are all different.
```

REI lists it as S-Tall, which is probably the same as S-Long. On the REI link it gives the following explanation for what Tall means:

> TALL: Some shirts, pants and jackets are available in tall sizes, which generally means an inseam that is 3 inches longer and a rise that is 1 inch longer

In this case though it seems the difference is only 1.5 in for size small.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'the difference is only 1.5 in for size small'?

Comment: S-Long = 33. S-Med (normal)=31.5. 33-31.5 = 1.5. My point was REI says 3 but in this case it is 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

TALL: Some shirts, pants and jackets are available in tall sizes, which generally means an inseam that is 3 inches longer ***and a rise that is 1 inch longer,***
From your REI link.
Tall just means thorough

Comment: From review: "Tall just means thorough"?  What do you mean by this?

Comment: In this case, that reading the charts is crucial. Instead of conflating two things and skimming. ↲ REI's chart, for instance, _doesnt list any tall sizes on their measuring guide_. What it does have is measurements by class (s, m, l, etc) and measurements by waist circumferance (2 typical american conventions). But nowehere on that chart is tall listed.. instead you're instructed to mentally adjust those sizes (easy enough).
↲ Similarly absent is "tall" from the N Face guide. But because primed for tall from REI, long is read as tall. And being rightmost primes us to misread the REI chart.